# Parsing command line parameters

Tags: python, command-line

As an example of my problem consider the following situation:

1. A user launches a program from command line with a syntax similar to this

   ```
   python prog.py "hi there" hi=Hello there=World!
   ```
2. The output of the program is "Hello World!".

My question refers to the part of parsing the arguments. How can I save the information contained in the "hi=Hello there=World!" part in order to use it? From there I should be able to do something with it.

I don't have the slightest idea of what the parameters are going to be so the solution needs to be as generic as possible.

Comment: Use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module.

Comment: Or use `docopt` It is simpler.

Comment: Copy/pasting your question title into google gives three Python modules for doing this as the top results.

Comment: @Lattyware Except I would avoid `optparse` as it is deprecated.

Comment: @AlexThornton Indeed, there is a large warning at the top of that page linking to argparse.

Comment: Yes I thought about using `argparse` but the parsing needs to be as generic as possible (I do not have the slightest idea about the names that I may have to parse).

Comment: @user1790813 Try to include that kind of thing in your question, it will make the answers more relevant.

Comment: @user1790813 I used to use `argparse`, then `plac` and ended with `docopt`, the latest being most flexible and easiest to use, as it allows any combination of parameters you may imagine and you do not have to care about confliting names of your command line parameters and Python reserved workds.

Comment: http://click.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do something like this... save this as "argtest.py":

```
import sys

def main(x):
    print(x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     print sys.argv #notice this is whatever you put in the arguments
     print sys.argv[0] # this is the name of the file you used
     main(sys.argv[1])
```

this will pass the first arg into main()

so if you are running from command line

```
 python argtest.py hello
```

your output will be

```
 hello
```

in your `main()` you would of course define whatever you want to do with the argument

personally i do my parsing in under the `if __name__=="__main__":` line usually something like `arguments = [x.split('=') for x in sys.argv[1:]] #if you want to seperate arguments like "pie=apple fart=stinky"`

`sys.argv` is a list of whatever you put after `python argtest.py` space seperated

for example if you do `python argtest.py apple pie comma poop`

```
sys.argv[1] == 'apple'
sys.argv[2] == 'pie'
sys.argv[3] == 'comma'
sys.argv[4] == 'poop'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/)

install docopt:

```
$ pip install docopt
```

Write the code of `prog.py`:

```
"""
Usage:
    prog.py <greeting> <name>
"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
    print "------"
    name = args["<name>"]
    greeting = args["<greeting>"]
    print "{greeting} {name}!".format(greeting=greeting, name=name)
```

Use it:

First see usage instructions:

```
$ python prog.py
Usage:
    prog.py <greeting> <name>
```

Then use it:

```
$ python prog.py Ola Mundi
{'<greeting>': 'Ola',
 '<name>': 'Mundi'}
------
Ola Mundi!
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using simple string processing:

```
import sys

entry = {}

for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    pos = i.find("=")
    entry[i[:pos]] = i[pos+1:]
```